# Telnet connection to Debian machine refused

Tags: linux, networking, debian, telnet

I'm trying to connect Debian 8 machine via telnet but I get login error shown in below

```
# telnet 192.168.88.48 
Trying 192.168.88.48... 
Connected to 192.168.88.48.
Escape character is '^]'. 
Debian GNU/Linux 8 login: Cannot possibly work without effective root
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

When I check the telnet server, it's working on the machine.

```
# netstat -tulpn | grep :23 
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:23 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 1817/inetd
```

What problem can be?

Comment: Answered here [command line - No effective root - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/276172/no-effective-root)

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for. I didn't enter any username to log in. I just tried to telnet connection.

Comment: Isn't the port mandatory for telnet? E.g. `telnet 192.168.88.48 23`

Comment: @eblock from `man telnet`: "If not specified, the telnet port (23) is used."

Comment: Okay, then nevermind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `in.telnetd` binary in package `telnetd` is running by default as an unprivileged process with user *telnetd*, probably for security reasons and privileges separation:

```
# grep telnet /etc/inetd.conf 
telnet      stream  tcp nowait  telnetd /usr/sbin/tcpd  /usr/sbin/in.telnetd
```

It then uses an helper process for handling the actual login. This helper process is setuid root. On a Debian 8 system that would give (except the date and size of the file, the same as on Debian 10):

```
# dpkg -S /usr/lib/telnetlogin
telnetd: /usr/lib/telnetlogin
# ls -l /usr/lib/telnetlogin
-rwsr-xr-x. 1 root telnetd 8112 Jul 22  2008 /usr/lib/telnetlogin
```

If you remove the setuid bit to this helper, you get exactly OP's error message.

This setuid bit is normally set during the package's post-installation in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/telnetd.postinst`:

> ```
> if [ -z "$(dpkg-statoverride --list /usr/lib/telnetlogin)" ]; then
>   chown root:telnetd /usr/lib/telnetlogin
>   chmod 4754 /usr/lib/telnetlogin
> fi
> ```

For example the set-uid bit could have been manually removed, overriden in *dpkg-statoverride*'s database or the package not been completely installed. Or OP's *in.telnetd* is running in a restricted environment. Some examples could be a filesystem mounted with *nosuid*,  perhaps including containers, or unadequate settings with AppArmor or SELinux.

Of course using *telnetd* itself should never be done. There used to be an SSL version available for telnet [client](https://packages.debian.org/sid/telnet-ssl) and [server](https://packages.debian.org/sid/telnetd-ssl), but considering it's not available in Debian *stable* (but only *sid*) it might have issues on its own.

Comment: Thank you !! It was related setuid permission of ```/usr/lib/telnetlogin```. I have changed it manually and telnet is working now.